# php mysql get un repeat value

Tags: php, mysql

```
id | tags
1  | photo article
2  | blog article
3  | blog
4  | logs
5  | photo article
6  | comment article
```

How to get all the `words` from `tags` un repeat?

I want print out `photo article blog logs comment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
  foreach (explode(' ', $row['tags']) as $word) {
    $array[$word] = $word;
  }
}
```

Comment: *Finally* someone **understood** the question.

Comment: `foreach ($results as $row) {` should be `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `tags` is a space-delimited list of actual tags in your layout. Using `SELECT DISTINCT` or `array_unique()` might produce the same results as your table has entries.

This snippet should get you the unique results:

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT `tags` FROM `table`');
$unique = array();

while (FALSE !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)))
{
   $tags = explode(' ', $row['tags']);
   foreach ($tags as $tag)
   {
      $unique[$tag] = 1;
   }
}

mysql_free_result($q);
```

The result are the `array_keys()` of `$unique`.

---

This might solve your problem. Though I suggest you rethink your design and change your table layout to allow for one `id` to have a one-to-many relation to `tag`.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` to not include any SQL results that are duplicates

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the GROUP BY operator in MySQL. You could use it like this:

`SELECT * FROM xxx GROUP BY tags`